# Trying to compile GWT with eclipse 4.14

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, gwt, compilation

I downloaded a gwt project and tried to compile it with eclipse 4.14.
it has an eclipse launcher file, which I can use to start super dev mode and access the webview from my browser of choice, and its working fine!

Problem now: how can I get it to actually compile into files (so that I have the raw .html .css and .javascript files)?
When I watch videos of people compiling gwt, they always have a google button in their toolbar, which I did not have. so I tried to install gwt plugins, I now have a red "GDT pulldown" symbol in my toolbar which gives me the option to compile the project. it brings up a popup window on which project I want to compile, if I select my product it asks me to select one of two entry point modules (module ore baseletmodule).

When choosing a module, it tells me that

```
Loading inherited module '.module' 
  [ERROR] Invalid module name: '.module'
```

when choosing the other, it tells me that

```
Compiling module com.BaseletElements
   Ignored 54 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   [ERROR] Module has no entry points defined
```

Soooo I can't really make sense of this, I feel like the module is the one I should go with, google reveals that you should change the name of the module to a valid name, but as a said, its an open-source project, so the compilation must have worked for other people with the same names. what do I do from here?

Comment: a reference to that module can help, so at least to answer this question we need to know how it was generated and what maven plugin it uses.

Comment: Building with maven instead of the gwt plugin helped and worked perfectly, thank you very much